# removing property of my last child of div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove a `property from my css class for my last-child`. Below is my container.

```
<div class="progress-stacked" id="progress-div">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail"></div>
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail"></div>
</div>
```

Below is my `css` class.

```
.progress-bar-fail {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    background-image: none;
    width: 9%; 
    margin-right: 11px;
}
```

How can i remove the `margin-right` property on my last child from my css class `dynamically`. I tried something below, but it seems not to work.

```
$("#progress-div :last-child").css('margin-right', '');
```

Comment: Try `$("#progress-div:last-child").css('margin-right', 'auto');` The "auto" is default value for margins.

Comment: Why are you doing this with jQuery, when CSS could do it? @TylerH: but then he'd be selecting the wrong element.

Comment: @DavidThomas: How would you do this in CSS?

Comment: I'd think that `#progress-div :last-child { margin-right : auto; }` should work? Though you may need to add the classes as well, in order to be more specific, but the `id` of the parent should address that all by itself. However, `#progress-div .progress-bar-fail:last-child` should (from what code we can see in your question) work.

Comment: @DavidThomas Ah, I didn't look closely enough at the ID/class names :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("#progress-div div:last-child").css('margin-right', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target this as you have both in css directly or in jQuery:

$(#progress-div .progress-bar-fail:last-child).css('margin-right', 'initial');

**Why doesn't it work to set the value to an empty string?** Because jQuery doesn't actually modify your css, it simply sets the values inline.  As inline styles have the highest priority in terms of cascade, they override any other css elsewhere in style tags or external stylesheets.  If a value is already inline, either because you manually added it to your markup or added it there via jQuery or Javascript, ***then*** setting the css property value to an empty string in jQuery will actually remove the value.

As for the value, if you specifically want the margin to be 0, then of course as @weivall suggested set the value to 0.  Otherwise, I would suggest using ***initial*** which sets the property to its default value.